# How come I cannot improve, only accept/deny, tag excerpts through suggested edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

Sometimes a users suggests an edit for tag wiki excerpts that needs a bit of improvement. As in the following screenshot, I wanted to remove the typos he introduced and leave the rest of his improvement.

However, I cannot "improve" the tag. The button isn't there. When I go to the tag, I cannot edit it. The only way is to accept, wait for another accept and then edit, which is cumbersome and it may move away from my radar before I get to it, leaving the errors.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot "improve" the tag wiki because you don't have full editing privileges for tag wikis yet. That requires ["trusted user" status](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user), or at least 20k reputation.

Until you become a "trusted user", you have to suggest edits to tag wikis and have them approved by other community members just like the person who suggested the initial edit.

Approval/rejection of tag wiki edits is a significantly lower bar, only requiring [5k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits).

The reason that you can use the "Improve" button on edits to regular posts is because you *do* have full editing privileges for regular posts. Anyone [over 2k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) has that privilege, the same group of people who can accept/reject suggested edits.

There used to be a bug where the "Improve" button was shown for users without full editing privileges for tag wikis, but clicking on it lead to an error page. The UI has since been improved so that the button is not shown at all when it does not apply.

Comment: That explains it (I only have near 12k rep). Yet, I'd consider approve/reject a higher privilege than editing, or at least equal. It's a bit unlucky in cases like this when a suggestion is good, but requires a bit of improvement.

Comment: @Abel: Accept/reject privileges are attained at the same time as full edit privileges for regular posts (questions and answers). The quirk is that only 10k+ users can see the dashboard with *all* of the suggested edits. Other users have to happen across a post with a pending suggested edit and approve it from there. As for tag wikis, they recently changed from the old system that no one understood to one where *anyone* can suggest edits. I'm not sure why 5k was picked as the threshold for accept/reject privileges, but it was. And only 20k users have *full* edit privs for tag wikis.

Comment: I agree it can be inconvenient, though. I have less than 20k here on Meta still, and I often find myself wishing for that "Improve" button!

Answer (score 2):

There should be an option to improve, that automatically goes back in to the queue. I've seen instances where a tag wiki entry needs work, but the edit wasn't terrible overall, and I don't know if I should reject it, or improve it. There is no way to edit it until the decision has been made to keep or reject it. That just doesn't seem right...