# Improving a tag wiki entry not an option

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, edits

I am on a new private beta, and looking at tag wiki entries. I see some that are good fundamentally, but perhaps have a small error, like a spelling error. I can't figure out a way to improve the edit, either by accepting it, or trying to manually edit it. Is there a way to do this, and if not, can we make there be a way to do it?

Comment: Related: [How come I cannot improve, only accept/deny, tag excerpts through suggested edits?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101663) (although the privilege thresholds are lower on private beta sites)

Answer (score 1):

Trusted Users are allowed to improve tag wiki edits - but this bar is generally fairly high rep (iirc it's something like 1k in private beta, 4k in public beta).

The privilege is the same one as being able to edit tag wikis without needing approval (since improvement of suggested edits is essentially doing exactly that).