# What is the purpose of showing score in suggested tag wiki edits?

Tags: support, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

While reviewing suggested edits, I found that tag wiki edit suggestions have vote score on the left

[image]

In my understanding the score is for letting reviewer know how important/useful a post is so that they can review carefully. But what purpose does it serve in tag wiki edits?

Comment: This vote element is also not subject to the [vote breakout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) privilege, which probably means it's just a dummy vote class. This could probably be tagged as a bug.

Comment: @Spevacus Vote breakout doesn't work in Suggested Edits for posts also (another bug?).

Comment: The vote count isn’t new; it’s appeared in [screenshots from 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101663/289905).

Comment: Probably part of the reason for seeing the votes (other than favoring the tag's creation) is [disdain for plagiarism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165379/282094), and it's a [status-completed duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146674/282094); so should be re-reported.

Comment: I've gone ahead and tagged this as a bug, per Rob's comment as well as a few others.

Comment: @Spevacus It's not really a regression, since as the answer there says, the only thing that was fixed was the fact that it says "answered" instead of "created".

Answer (score 4):

The review page for tag wiki edits no longer displays a vote count, so I imagine the developers/project managers of the [review queue design overhaul](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360198/622284) determined that showing a score on this page wasn't useful (as did most of us, I imagine).

To see for yourself, here's a [recently approved tag wiki edit review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/78604). No score is visible on the left of the page as the old UI indicated.