# Enable vote breakout and the timeline button on suggested edit reviews

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, timeline

At the [Established User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) privilege level, you gain the ability to break out the vote counts into up and down votes, which is very useful in determining whether a post is generally well-received, disputed, or negatively-received.

Additionally, the [timeline button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post/342316#342316) has recently been made easily accessible to all.

However, on suggested edit reviews, neither of these actions are accessible.

*These actions are available during [close vote reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/71144) and queues like Triage on SO, but they are not available during [suggested edit reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/70950).

Can we enable the vote breakout privilege and the timeline button on suggested edit reviews, please? This would be pretty useful (avoids having to open the question in an new tab), and would preserve consistency between the close vote queue and the suggested edit queue.

*As a note, this would be [useless on suggested Tag wiki edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345251/what-is-the-purpose-of-showing-score-in-suggested-tag-wiki-edits), which shouldn't have vote counts at all.*

<sub>*Example links posted for those of you over 1k rep. who'd like to try the vote breakout yourselves.</sub>

Comment: How does the actual voting influence your decision if an edit is good or not? The timeline might be useful to see prior edits, but the vote count?

Comment: A fair point, @Tom . The timeline would be far more useful, however the vote breakout being available would ensure consistency. It's far more useful during close vote reviews, when you're determining the standing of a post, but I figure if the timeline should be available, why not the privilege people amassed reputation for and "earned," in a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the introduction of the [review queue overhaul](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360198/622284), this is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Here's a demonstration of me toying with it, taken from [this review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/70950):

[image: Demonstration of the vote breakout and timeline button (mouseover) in a suggested edit review]